# redux reset props after redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using redux and had problem with this code in my component

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.data.deleted_ad){
        this.props.history.replace('/')
    }
  }
```

The problem with this code is that when I nagivate from '/' to 'ad', this will bring me back to '/' again.

Here's my reducer look like

```
case 'DELETE_AD_PENDING':
      return { 
        ...state, 
        loading: true
      }
    case 'DELETE_AD_FULFILLED':
      return {
        ...state,
        deleted_ad: action.payload.data.success === true ? true : false
      }
    case 'DELETE_AD_REJECTED':
      return { 
        ...state, 
        loading: false, 
        error: action.payload.response.data.error
      }
```

It's partially working, but not after user click into a new ad because `nextProps.data.deleted_ad` is still true after the redirect.

Comment: in the reducer of new app, just set deleted_ad: false, hm?

Comment: What is your `new` reducer look like ?

Answer (score 1):

Try [react-router-redux (react-router 4 example)](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux) ! It works beautifully. You don't have to worry about such props as `is_deleted` in your component for redirection - you can keep them but don't use them for redirection (I would use them only for rendering)

You put ALL HISTORY into redux and then act an async action for redirection after a successful action. Like this:

In your component (create form component example with a form on submit):

```
 /* components/Create.js */

 import {addMeeting} from "../../store/actions/meetingActions";

 class Create extends Component {
     ....
     onSubmit(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         this.props.dispatch(addMeeting(this.state.meeting));
    }
    ....
  }
```

In your actions declarations (using thunk middleware):

```
 /* meetingActions.js */

 import axios from "axios/index";
 import {push} from 'react-router-redux';

 export function addMeeting(meeting) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch({type: 'ADD_MEETING_STARTED'});

        axios.post('/api/meeting', meeting)
            .then((res) => {
                 dispatch({type: 'ADD_MEETING_FULFILLED', payload:res.data})
                 dispatch(push('/'));   // <--- HERE
              })
            .catch((err) => {
                 dispatch({type: 'ADD_MEETING_ERROR', payload:err.response.data.errors})
             });
    }
}
```

You can see a full example of how it works in my repository of basic MERN CRUD stack SPA right [here](https://github.com/sweettirexkiller/basic-react-crud). The code that is might interest you most is in `client/store` directory.

This solution has an advantage that you will never associate redirection with a component but with an action instead. You can add a second argument to action `addMeeting(meeting, redirectTo)` to specify where router should go after action.

redux-logger shows this:

[image: console-logs]

Hope it helped!